# The obscure message

Tags: cipher

I created this puzzle. Find the message.

q螣 s䈚 q蟝 v쀎 q蟾 q蠸 q襪 q褰 q弧 q螣  q襪  q蛡 q袈 q蟝

Hint 1:

> Everyone can solve this puzzle

Hint 2:

> How do you feel about this? (Yes, this is a hint.)

Comment: Rot 13(Vg frrzf gung nyy bs gur flzobyf ner rvgure Puvarfr be Wncnarfr naq pna or genafyngrq vavgb Ratyvfu rkprcg bar. V pnaabg genafyngr gur sbhegu bar (쀎) naq vg ybbxf zber yvxr Xberna guna nal bgure ynathntr.)

Comment: @WilliamPennanti, I applaud your effort sincerely. Take a careful look at Hint 1. Hope you fill find the answer :)

Comment: @WilliamPennanti Rot13(Vg vf vaqrrq Xberna (Unathy), ebhtuyl genafyngvat gb "oohrez". Ohg V unir n srryvat guvf vf tvoorevfu, orpnhfr vg vf rkprrqvatyl ener sbe punenpgref gb or pbzcbfrq bs 5 cnegf (yrggref) yvxr guvf punenpgre (gur "oo", "h", "r", "e" naq "z".) Creuncf gur chmmyr vf abg ybbxvat sbe zrnavat be hfr, znlor fbzrguvat nobhg gur punenpgref vgfrys?)

Comment: Besides, Rot13(bgure guna 弧 (juvpu zrnaf nep), gurfr punenpgref ner nyy cerggl hapbzzba nf n Puvarfr fcrnxre zlfrys. Guvf, gbtrgure jvgu Uvag 1 vzcyvrf gb zr gung vg'f fbzrguvat ryfr (creuncf gur cebahapvngvba)?)

Comment: Rot13(Lbh ner trggvat pybfre. Ohg abg ng vg.) @titaniummorro

Comment: Looks like some chineese or japaneese scripture

Comment: rot13(Qbrf guvf vaibyir pbairegvat gb Havpbqr?)

Comment: Lbh funyy gel jung lbh guvax. Ohg V pna'g gryy gung. Fbeel, @TobyMak.